# Visual Studio 2015 keeps opening new files in the FindResults Window

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Since today Visual Studio keeps opening new files in the FindResults Window.
I keep moving the new tab into the window where all the other open files are 
-- but I'm tired of doing this, since it is obviously a setting (I figured so, since this behavior is new. And who enabled it?)
Anybody any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (Window -> Reset Window Layout) ;